# A way to always dodge a histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot2 I'm creating a histogram with a factor on the horizontal axis and another factor for the fill color, using a dodged position. My problem is that the fill factor sometimes takes only one value for a value of the horizontal factor, and with nothing to dodge the bar takes up the full width. Is there a way to make it dodge nothing so that all bar widths are the same? Or equivalently to plot the 0's?

For example

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = factor(carb), fill = factor(gear))) +
geom_histogram(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101710/903061) has a couple ideas. It was also asked before the new version was released, so maybe something changed? Using facets (also shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7104847/903061)) I don't like for my situation, though I suppose editing the data and using `geom_bar` could work, but it feels inelegant. Moreover, when I tried facetting anyway

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(carb), fill = factor(gear))) +
    geom_bar() + facet_grid(~factor(carb))
```

I get the error "Error in layout_base(data, cols, drop = drop): 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting"

I suppose I could generate a data frame of counts and then use `geom_bar`,

```
mtcounts <- ddply(subset(mtcars, select = c("carb", "gear")),
    .fun = count, .variables = c("carb", "gear"))
```

filling out the levels that aren't present with 0's. Does anyone know if that would work or if there's a better way?

Comment: I know you don't consider it ideal, but I think pre-calculating the counts and using geom_bar would be my preferred way of doing this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated**  `geom_bar` needs `stat = "identity"`

I'm not sure if this is too late for you, but see the answer to a recent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326729/dont-drop-zero-count-dodged-barplot/10329045#10329045)
That is, I'd take Joran's advice to pre-calculate the counts outside the `ggplot` call and to use `geom_bar`. As with the answer to other post, the counts are obtained in two steps: first, a crosstabulation of counts is obtained using `dcast`; then second, `melt` the crosstabulation.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

dat = dcast(mtcars, factor(carb) ~ factor(gear), fun.aggregate = length)
dat.melt = melt(dat, id.vars = "factor(carb)", measure.vars = c("3", "4", "5"))
dat.melt

(p <- ggplot(dat.melt, aes(x = `factor(carb)`, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge"))
```

The chart:

[image]

Comment: Care to attach the final result image, too?

Comment: I've added the chart, and made a couple of editorial changes to clarify the response.

Comment: Never too late! Thanks for expanding that comment into a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

As shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48343620/903061), in newer versions  of `ggplot2` (version >= 2.2.1.900) there is a simpler way: `position_dodge` gains a `preserve` argument that if set to `"single"` will always dodge.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = factor(carb), fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

[image]