# Don't drop zero count: dodged barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a dodged barplot in ggplot2 and one grouping has a zero count that I want to display.  I remembered seeing this on [HERE](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/b520e0be08f5d100) a while back and figured the `scale_x_discrete(drop=F)` would work.  It does not appear to work with dodged bars.  How can I make the zero counts show?

For instance, (code below) in the plot below, type8~group4 has no examples. I would still like the plot to display the empty space for the zero count instead of eliminating the bar.  How can I do this?

[image]

```
mtcars2 <- data.frame(type=factor(mtcars$cyl), 
    group=factor(mtcars$gear))

m2 <- ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x=type , fill=group))
p2 <- m2 + geom_bar(colour="black", position="dodge") +
        scale_x_discrete(drop=F)
p2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way I know of is to pre-compute the counts and add a dummy row:

```
dat <- rbind(ddply(mtcars2,.(type,group),summarise,count = length(group)),c(8,4,NA))

ggplot(dat,aes(x = type,y = count,fill = group)) + 
    geom_bar(colour = "black",position = "dodge",stat = "identity")
```

[image]

I thought that using `stat_bin(drop = FALSE,geom = "bar",...)` instead would work, but apparently it does not.

Comment: Not as easy as I was hoping but couldn't find an appropriate answer in my search so I should have figured it would take some reworking.  Thanks Joran.  Worked very well +1

Comment: @TylerRinker Honestly, I feel like `stat_bin(drop = FALSE, geom = "bar",position = "dodge",...)` _should_ do this; at least, the documentation strongly suggests that it would. I'd be very curious to hear from more knowledgable folks on the mailing list why it doesn't.

Comment: I'm working on a project right now but I'll throw it up on the list later and report back here.

Answer (score 33):

Here's how you can do it without making summary tables first.
It did not work in my CRAN versioin (2.2.1) but in the latest development version of ggplot (2.2.1.900) I had no issues.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html

Comment: `preserve = "single"` saved my life ;)

Comment: preserve = "single" works great! However, it doesn't move the bar labels. When I use geom_text the labels for the "single" bars are in the not displayed in the middle of the bar.

Answer (score 17):

**Updated**  `geom_bar()` needs `stat = "identity"`

For what it's worth: The table of counts, dat, above contains NA. Sometimes, it is useful to have an explicit 0 instead; for instance, if the next step is to put counts above the bars. The following code does just that, although it's probably no simpler than Joran's. It involves two steps: get a crosstabulation of counts using `dcast`, then melt the table using `melt`, followed by `ggplot()` as usual.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
mtcars2 = data.frame(type=factor(mtcars$cyl), group=factor(mtcars$gear))

dat = dcast(mtcars2, type ~ group, fun.aggregate = length)
dat.melt = melt(dat, id.vars = "type", measure.vars = c("3", "4", "5"))
dat.melt

ggplot(dat.melt, aes(x = type,y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black", position = position_dodge(width = .8), width = 0.7) +
  ylim(0, 14) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_dodge(width = .8), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: This wound up being a bit nicer.  I'd already completed the graphic and it took some hackish junk but this solved those problems.  Nice response. +1

Answer (score 8):

I asked this same question, but I only wanted to use `data.table`, as it's a faster solution for much larger data sets. I included notes on the data so that those that are less experienced and want to understand why I did what I did can do so easily. Here is how I manipulated the `mtcars` data set:

```
library(data.table)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
mtcars$Cylinders <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl) # Creates new column with data from cyl called Cylinders as a factor. This allows ggplot2 to automatically use the name "Cylinders" and recognize that it's a factor
mtcars$Gears <- as.factor(mtcars$gear) # Just like above, but with gears to Gears
setkey(mtcars, Cylinders, Gears) # Set key for 2 different columns
mtcars <- mtcars[CJ(unique(Cylinders), unique(Gears)), .N, allow.cartesian = TRUE] # Uses CJ to create a completed list of all unique combinations of Cylinders and Gears. Then counts how many of each combination there are and reports it in a column called "N"
```

And here is the call that produced the graph

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=Cylinders, y = N, fill = Gears)) + 
               geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
               ylab("Count") + theme(legend.position="top") + 
               scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

And it produces this graph:

[image: Cylinder Graph]

Furthermore, if there is continuous data, like that in the `diamonds` data set (thanks to mnel):

```
library(data.table)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

diamonds <- data.table(diamonds) # I modified the diamonds data set in order to create gaps for illustrative purposes
setkey(diamonds, color, cut) 
diamonds[J("E",c("Fair","Good")), carat := 0]
diamonds[J("G",c("Premium","Good","Fair")), carat := 0]
diamonds[J("J",c("Very Good","Fair")), carat := 0]
diamonds <- diamonds[carat != 0]
```

Then using `CJ` would work as well.

```
data <- data.table(diamonds)[,list(mean_carat = mean(carat)), keyby = c('cut', 'color')] # This step defines our data set as the combinations of cut and color that exist and their means. However, the problem with this is that it doesn't have all combinations possible
data <- data[CJ(unique(cut),unique(color))] # This functions exactly the same way as it did in the discrete example. It creates a complete list of all possible unique combinations of cut and color
ggplot(data, aes(color, mean_carat, fill=cut)) +
             geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
             ylab("Mean Carat") + xlab("Color")
```

Giving us this graph:

[image: Diamonds Fixed]

Answer (score 4):

Use `count` and `complete` from `dplyr` to do this.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
    mutate(
        type = as.factor(cyl),
        group = as.factor(gear)
    ) %>%
    count(type, group) %>% 
    complete(type, group, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = type, y = n, fill = group)) +
        geom_bar(colour = "black", position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Very nice...I suspect that the next release of ggplot2 to CRAN will contain @S_BRT's answer which seems like the ebst solution https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/position-dodge.r

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit the feature of the `table()` function, which computes the number of occurrences of a factor for *all* its levels

```
# load plyr package to use ddply
library(plyr) 

# compute the counts using ddply, including zero occurrences for some factor levels
df <- ddply(mtcars2, .(group), summarise, 
 types = as.numeric(names(table(type))), 
 counts = as.numeric(table(type)))

# plot the results
ggplot(df, aes(x = types, y = counts, fill = group)) +
 geom_bar(stat='identity',colour="black", position="dodge")
```

[image]