# Leaving a space in geom_bar with stat='bin', position='dodge' and zeroes

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I am plotting some data like this:

```
x = data.frame(cat=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), type=c('x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'x'))
ggplot(x, aes(cat, fill=type)) + geom_bar(stat='bin', position='dodge')
```

Which gives me a plot like this:

[image]

However, what I want is for the bars to all be the same width, such that there is an empty space for cat=='b' where the blue bar would be. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a potential solution, although I would be happy to hear if there is something better.

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(table(x$cat, x$type)), aes(Var1, Freq, fill=Var2)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

Comment: Fine by me, why would you like anything else?

Comment: I was hoping there was a way that didn't require the slightly hacky detour via table().

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this via specifying some arguments for stat_bin: follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326729/dont-drop-zero-count-dodged-barplot).
The solution adapted to your case may look like

```
require(reshape2)
x_dcast <- dcast(x, type ~ cat, fun.agg = length)
x_melt <- melt(x_dcast, id.vars = "type")
ggplot(x_melt, aes(variable, value, fill=type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

Note that your answer can be modified a bit:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(table(x)), aes(Var1, Freq, fill=Var2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

You can see that your answer is more transparent. You will have to compute counts manually anyways.

Speaking about "slightly hacky" -- from my experience, this is a common approach for non-standard situations in R. If it does the job and is a readable one-liner, why not?