# Create Barplot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a data of the following type:

```
Model No.   Rank
1            1
2            2
1            1
3            1
1            2
2            2
3            2
1            3
2            1
2            2
3            3
3            3
```

Now I want to have a barplot similar to the following picture:

[image]

My chart will have

1. "Model Number" on the x-axis label instead of "Non Smoker" and "smoker"
2. The bars will be the ranks (i.e., separate bars for rank 1,rank2 and rank 3)
3. The y-axis will contain the frequency
4. The legend will have the Rank category

So, for Model1: the 1st bar will be for rank 1 and the corresponding value on y-axis will be 2, as there are two rank 1 entries for model 1. And similar concept for models 2 and 3.

How can this be achieved in R?

Answer (score 3):

I would recoment using `ggplot2` for a nice plot output

```
    require(ggplot2) 
    # creating sample data set | making it factors is crucial
    set.seed(1337) 
    model.no<-rep(1:4,each=5)
    rank<-sample(1:3,20,TRUE)
    dat<-data.frame(model.no=factor(model.no),rank=factor(rank))
    # Plot
    ggplot(data=dat, aes(model.no,fill=rank))+
      geom_bar(position="dodge") + xlab("Your x-label")+ylab("Your y-label")
```

This gives you the following output
[image: Barchart with ggplot]

P.S.:
If you dont want unused levels of rank to be droped, see 2 ways here:
[Don't drop zero count: dodged barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326729/dont-drop-zero-count-dodged-barplot)

Comment: what change should be done so that I have the proportion of ranks in each column instead of the count?

Comment: add `aes(y= ..count../ sum(..count..) )` to `geom_bar()`
and `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())` at the end

Comment: do you mean 
aes(y=count(Rank)/sum(count(model.no)) ?
sorry I am a newbie

Comment: Put `geom_bar(position="dodge",aes(y= ..count../ sum(..count..) ))` instead of `geom_bar(position="dodge")` and it should work

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(sample(5:50, 15), 
              ncol=3, 
              nrow=5, 
              dimnames=list(paste("Rank", 1:5),
                            paste("Model", 1:3)))
barplot(mat,beside=TRUE,col=2:6, ylim=c(0,100)) 
legend("topright", legend=rownames(mat), fill=2:6))
```

[image]

Comment: what change should be done so that I have the proportion of ranks in each column instead of the count?

Comment: @darkage: You can add `mat <- prop.table(mat, margin=2)` before `barplot` to e.g. plot the proportions per Model. You'd also need to adjust the `ylim` parameter in `barplot`.