# Shiny ggplot missing factor level

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to plot some charts in `R` using `ggplot package` in `ShinyDashboard`. Right now I am stuck with one problem.

[image]

In this example I have 6 different brands and 2 different categories. What I like to do, that all the brands would be plotted like `Brand7`. This mean, that all the brands should have 2 columns: `Bike66` and `Buss66`.
What is more, I always have 2 categories, but the names of it can change (you can use slider in reproducable example).

It is possible to solve the problem using ggplot settings or some lines with zero values should be added to `data.frame`?

All in all, I was unable to find proper solution.

Reproducable example below.

Thanks!

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)



# Header -----------------------------------------------------------

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard")

# Sidebar --------------------------------------------------------------

sm <- sidebarMenu(
  menuItem(
    text="Graph1",
    tabName="Graph1",
    icon=icon("home")
  )
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sm)

# Body --------------------------------------------------

body <- dashboardBody(

  # Layout  --------------------------------------------  

  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName="Graph1",

      fluidPage(
        fluidRow(


          box(
            title = "Season", width = 10, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,

            sliderInput("Slider", "Size:",
                        min = 1, max = 99, value = c(66)),

            plotOutput("Graph1"),
            plotOutput("Graph2")

          )  
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Setup Shiny app UI components -------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin="black")

# Setup Shiny app back-end components -------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Generate data --------------------------------------

  df <- reactive ({  

  set.seed(1992)
  n=8

  Category <- sample(c("Bike", "Bus"), n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
  Category <- paste0(Category, input$Slider)
  Category <- as.factor(Category)
  Brand <- sample("Brand", n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
  Brand <- paste0(Brand, sample(1:14, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL))
  USD <- abs(rnorm(n))*1000

  df <- data.frame(Brand, Category, USD)

  }) 

  # Inputs --------------------------------------




  # Plot --------------------------------

  output$Graph1 <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(df(), aes(x=Brand, y=USD, fill=Category))+
      geom_bar(stat='identity', position="dodge")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in the current form, you'll have to add [zero counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326729/dont-drop-zero-count-dodged-barplot).

But you can also solve it with facets (note that I don't think this has anything to do with `Shiny` per se):

## Sample data

```
set.seed(1992)
n=8

Category <- sample(c("Bike", "Bus"), n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
Category <- paste0(Category, input$Slider)
Category <- as.factor(Category)
Brand <- sample("Brand", n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
Brand <- paste0(Brand, sample(1:14, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL))
USD <- abs(rnorm(n))*1000

df <- data.frame(Brand, Category, USD)
```

## Create plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Category, y=USD, fill=Category)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position="dodge") + facet_grid(~Brand) +
  theme_classic()
```

## Result

[image]