# Is there a workaround for this failure to dodge in geom_violin?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If a data set includes at least three data points per cell, the dodging of violins works as expected. See the image below.

Dodge is as expeced
[image: Dodge is as expeced]

However, in the code that follows, there are only 2 data points in the 'Verbal Class B' cell. With just two data points, ggplot2 refuses to construct a violin, which I'm OK with. But as a side effect, the violin for the 'Verbal Class A' condition is horizontally misaligned, causing that violin to also be misaligned with the data points generated by geom_point. See the image, below.

Violin dodge fails and causes misalignment with other dodged elements
[image]

Is there a workaround to make the violin dodge properly so as to stay aligned with the data points?

```
Score = c( 9,12,6,12,11,10,4,12,11,10,9,9,14,8,12,11,10,11,4,10,11,17,6,15,8,12,14,1,16,3,18,16,15,11,10,14,8,8,12,15)
Topic = c( "Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Math","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal","Verbal")
Class = c( "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B")
#Class = c( "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B")
DataSet = data.frame(Topic,Class,Score)
mywidth <- 1.0 
mydodge <- 0.90
myjitteramount <- 0.35
ggplot (data = DataSet, aes(x = Topic, y = Score, color = Class))+
  geom_violin (draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), fill = NA, width = mywidth, position = position_dodge(mydodge), alpha = 1.0, size = 0.47, scale = "area", show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_point (position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = mydodge, jitter.height = 0, jitter.width = myjitteramount), shape = 21, size = 1.5, stroke = 0.7, fill = NA, alpha = 1.0, show.legend = TRUE)  +  
  ggsave ("TempPlot1.png", width = 11, height = 11, units = "in", dpi = 600)
```

Comment: related, but not really helping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020437/consistent-width-for-geom-bar-in-the-event-of-missing-data  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326729/dont-drop-zero-count-dodged-barplot

Comment: I feel that this may not very easily be possible - certainly with some bad hack it would be. What about avoiding geom_violin altogether and using ggbeeswarm::geom_beeswarm instead? You have so few data points that a violin plot is also not really helpful for visualisation.

Comment: This is a minimal working example, not my actual data. I actually have many, many data points in all all of the conditions except in one, in which there are only two data points. [RE: You have so few data points that a violin plot is also not really helpful for visualisation]

Comment: Understood - however, `geom_beeswarm` also works with "many many data points". You can always add an `alpha` or so - it will also, nice effect, shape like your violins when many data points. You can then always add a boxplot or so for your quartiles if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that this may not very easily be possible - certainly with some bad hack it would be.

If you want to keep your dodge, a less-than satisfying workaround is to create the violin plot with a different set of data (giving fake data to the last group), cover it with a rectangle, and overplot with your points.

```r
library(ggplot2)

Score <- c(9, 12, 6, 12, 11, 10, 4, 12, 11, 10, 9, 9, 14, 8, 12, 11, 10, 11, 4, 10, 11, 17, 6, 15, 8, 12, 14, 1, 16, 3, 18, 16, 15, 11, 10, 14, 8, 8, 12, 15)
Topic <- c("Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal", "Verbal")
Class1 <- c( "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B")
Class2 <- c( "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B")

DataSet1 <- data.frame(Topic, Class1, Score)
DataSet2 <- data.frame(Topic, Class2, Score)

ggplot() +
  geom_violin(data = DataSet1, aes(x = Topic, y = Score, color = Class1), draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75),  position = position_dodge()) +
  annotate(geom = 'rect', xmin = 2, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = 'white') +
  geom_point(data = DataSet2, aes(x = Topic, y = Score, color = Class2), position = position_jitterdodge())
```

[image]

A better option is probably to separate your data using `facet`. You can only really facet by class, which may make the comparison difficult, but at least the data points overlap the violins:

```r
ggplot(data = DataSet2, aes(x = Topic, y = Score, color = Class2)) +
  geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), position = position_dodge()) +
    geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  facet_grid(~Class2, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

Another option would be to reconsider your visualisation, e.g. using ggbeeswarm.

```r
library(ggbeeswarm)
ggplot(DataSet2, aes(x = Topic, y = Score, color = Class2)) +
  geom_beeswarm(dodge.width = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I feel that the

**_"create the violin plot with a different set of data (giving fake data to the last group), cover it with a rectangle, and overplot with your points"_**

is the best example, so far, of a workaround (though it is awkward, and far from ideal).

Comment: @user1113568 I agree it's far from ideal. I'd probaly use `geom_beeswarm`, but if you really want a good solution with `geom_violin`, this may indeed warrant a feature request on github. - although I doubt this will have high priority for the developers

Comment: @user1113568 to make the awkward solution look better, you could remove the grid lines and use the same fill as the panel background