# How to add 0 counts on x-axis using geom_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Lets say I have

[image]

As you can see, there are **0 Complete Response** in `WHO-1`, but there are cases in the other categories. So, it looks graphically off that there are three `geom_col`-bars in the `WHO-1`-category and four `geom_col`-bars in the other two.

How can I add a fourth bar to `WHO-1` indicating the space corresponding to **Complete Response**?

Something like

[image]

Script

```
pp %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(nyWHO = as.factor(WHO),
         best.resp = as.factor(case_when(best_rad == "CR" ~ 4,
                                         best_rad == "PR" ~ 3,
                                         best_rad == "SD" ~ 2,
                                         best_rad == "PD" ~ 1))) %>%
  count(nyWHO, best.resp) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(nyWHO, n, color = best.resp, fill= best.resp))  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("#6DBCC3", "#8B3A62", "grey40", "#E1B930"), 0.4), 
                    name="",
                    labels = c("Progressive disease", "Stable disease", "Partial response", "Complete response")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols, 
                      name="",
                      labels = c("Progressive disease", "Stable disease", "Partial response", "Complete response"))  + 
  geom_col(width=1, position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single"), 
            vjust=-0.5, size = 10, show.legend = F) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "", labels = c("WHO-1", "WHO-2", "WHO-3")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="", breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 20)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 80)) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 22),
                axis.title.y = element_text(size = 22),
                axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(color = "grey20", size = 20),
                axis.text.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 18),
                panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray90", size = 1.2),
                panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "gray90", size = 0.6),
                legend.text = element_text(size = 22),
                legend.position = "top")
```

Data

pp <- structure(list(WHO = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L,
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L,
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L,
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1",
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), best_rad = c("SD", "SD", "CR",
"CR", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "CR", "CR",
"PR", "PR", "PR", "SD", "PD", "PR", "PD", "SD", "SD", "PD", "PD",
"PD", "PD", "SD", "PD", "PR", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "PD",
"SD", "SD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD",
"PD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "PD", "PD",
"SD", "SD", "SD", "PD", "SD", "PD", "SD", "SD", "PD", "PD", "SD",
"PD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "PD", "SD", "PD", "SD",
"PD", "SD", "PD", "SD", "PD", "SD", "SD", "PD", "SD", "SD", "SD",
"PD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "CR",
"SD", "SD", "SD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD",
"SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD",
"PD", "PD", "SD", "SD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "PD")), row.names = c(NA,
-133L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10326729/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(nyWHO, best.resp, .drop = FALSE)`

```
d <- pp %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(nyWHO = as.factor(WHO),
         best.resp = as.factor(case_when(best_rad == "CR" ~ 4,
                                         best_rad == "PR" ~ 3,
                                         best_rad == "SD" ~ 2,
                                         best_rad == "PD" ~ 1))) %>%
  count(nyWHO, best.resp, .drop = FALSE)
d
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   nyWHO best.resp     n
   <fct> <fct>     <int>
 1 1     1            11
 2 1     2            41
 3 1     3             3
 4 1     4             0
 5 2     1            22
 6 2     2            13
 7 2     3             5
 8 2     4             1
 9 3     1            23
10 3     2             9
11 3     3             1
12 3     4             4

ggplot(...)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `.drop = FALSE` is the solution, but if not possible say, the raw data is unavailable, then a solution is to expand the data for all the levels by using a join:

```
...
data <- pp %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(nyWHO = as.factor(WHO),
         best.resp = as.factor(case_when(best_rad == "CR" ~ 4,
                                         best_rad == "PR" ~ 3,
                                         best_rad == "SD" ~ 2,
                                         best_rad == "PD" ~ 1))) %>%
  count(nyWHO, best.resp) 

data %>% 
  full_join(expand(data, nyWHO, best.resp), by = c("nyWHO", "best.resp")) %>% 
  replace_na(list(n = 0)) %>% 

  ggplot(aes(nyWHO, n, color = best.resp, fill= best.resp))  +
... # rest of ggplot statement
```

[image]