# ggplot2 Display columns with zero values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some plots that I'd like to make sure there is three columns represented on the chart for each quadrat. Is there a way to make a small line appear on the columns that have an average of 0?

#### Current Plot

[image]

#### Current code

```
# plot average for each ellenberg category for each quadrat
i = 1
for (df in ellenCatTab){
  plotName <- names(ellenCatTab)[i]
  i = i + 1
  
  col_means <- colMeans(df[,5:31], na.rm=TRUE)
  col_meansdf <- stack(col_means)
  col_meansdf$Quadrat <- do.call(rbind, quadList)
  col_meansdf$Quadrat <- as.factor(col_meansdf$Quadrat)
  col_meansdf$Year <- do.call(rbind, yearList)
  col_meansdf$Year <- as.factor(col_meansdf$Year)
  col_meansdf <- col_meansdf[c('Quadrat', 'Year', 'values')]
  
  p <- ggplot(col_meansdf, aes(x=Quadrat, y=values, fill=Year)) +
           ggtitle(plotName) +
           labs(x='Quadrat', y='Average Ellenberg Score') +
           geom_col(width=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.5), drop=FALSE) +
           scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'YlGnBu') +
           theme_classic()

  plot(p)
  
  ggsave(plot=p, 
         file=paste0(plotName,'.png'), 
         limitsize=FALSE, 
         width=150, height=100, units="mm")
}
```

#### Sample Data Frame

```
structure(list(Quadrat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L), levels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", 
"Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9"), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("2019", "2020", 
"2022"), class = "factor"), values = c(0.0588235294117647, 0.105263157894737, 
0.0625, 0.0714285714285714, 0.0666666666666667, 0.0714285714285714, 
0.222222222222222, 0.12, 0.12, 0.0625, 0.0769230769230769, 0.0625, 
0.1, 0.1, NaN, 0.0625, 0, 0, 0.142857142857143, 0, 0.142857142857143, 
0.0588235294117647, 0.1, 0.0588235294117647, 0, 0.0909090909090909, 
0)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Use `geom_bar`, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326729/dont-drop-zero-count-dodged-barplot) for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is a hacky approach:

We could manipluate 0 values and change them to 0.001, and we also should replace NAs with 0.001:

```
libarary(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(values = ifelse(values == 0, 0.001, values),
         values = replace_na(values, 0.001)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Quadrat, y=values, fill=Year)) +
    labs(x='Quadrat', y='Average Ellenberg Score') +
    geom_col(width=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.5), drop=FALSE) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'YlGnBu') +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]