# R, ggplot bar, all bars same width?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to find a ggplot specific work around so that I can generate bar plots in which all the bars are the same width. I know that this is because I am "missing  values" and because the bar width fills in side-to-side over a blank. BUT I'm working with very large data sets and using reshape to make the data wide and then inserting place holder values to eliminate blanks is not something I want to do.

Test data:

```
df<-data.frame(tax=c("type1","type1","type1","type1","type2","type2"),Gene=c("a","b","c","c","a","b"),logFC=c(-2,-4,2,1,3,-1))
```

ggplot code, which gives me an extra wide bar for "c"

```
bar<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Gene, order=Gene,y=logFC,fill=tax))+ geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

Any suggestions that don't require me to change any values in the input df?

**This question is not a duplicate. I am looking for an ALTERNATIVE solution to what has been given before. Previous solutions DO NOT WORK. I cannot simply dcast (with fill=0) and re-melt my data frame (trust me, I've been trying this for weeks).
I am looking for a ggplot specific answer.

Comment: I think it will remain the wide bar because C has only type1 twice and it doesn't have type 2

Comment: Dupes: [Don't drop zero count dodges bar plot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10326729/903061), [always dodge a histogram](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10149571/903061), etc.

Comment: If you read the question, I understand why this is happening, and I've read how the other duplicate questioned are answered. I am looking for an alternate. Previous solutions DO NOT work with my data frame. I have too many variables and my datasets are too large.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will remain as a wide bar because c has only type1 twice and it doesn't have type 2

If you use facet_wrap, it will remain the same width

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Gene, y=logFC, color = tax))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge", width=.5) +
  facet_wrap(~tax)
```

[image]

Comment: This solution does work, but it does not solve my problem. As I cannot just separate my data as shown. I have too many variables and a facet wrap work around is not applicable to my data.

Comment: Then, in order to help you, you need to provide a reproducible example that is similar to your data! or share your data.