# How to get the plots side by side and that too sorted according to Fill in R Language

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

Data

```
Tool    Rating  Process
R       9   Data Handling
MATLAB  8   Data Handling
Excel   8   Data Handling
SQL     7   Data Handling
R       8   Programming
MATLAB  8   Programming
SAS     6   Programming
Python  4   Programming
R       8   Visualizations/Graphical Representations
Shiny   7   Visualizations/Graphical Representations
Excel   7   Visualizations/Graphical Representations
Tableau 5   Visualizations/Graphical Representations
```

I executed the following command

```
ggplot(bplot, aes(x=reorder(bplot$Tool, bplot$Rating), y=bplot$Rating,     fill=bplot$Process)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black") +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#669933", "#FFCC66", "#999999")) +
xlab("State")
```

and got the following plot as result

[image]

but I want all to be stacked/grouped horizontally not vertically.

While it plots also, I want it sorted out according to the filled colors from higher to lower.

If I am using the following command according to the comments, I am getting the plot like this.

Command executed is

```
ggplot(bplot, aes(x=reorder(Tool, Rating), y=Rating,      fill=bplot$Process)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", colour="black") +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#669933", "#FFCC66", "#999999")) +
xlab("State")
```

[image]

I want all the bars to be of same size and it should be grouped so that all the yellow ones come side by side, and similarly with grey and green ones.

Comment: You get stacked bars by default in `geom_bar`.  Sounds like you may want `position = "dodge"`.

Comment: @aosmith I am getting the following error when I used position = "dodge"

Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

Comment: This is the error you get when you don't use `stat = "identity"`.  Did you remove that from `geom_bar`?

Comment: Yes I have removed it. Please help me out guys.

Comment: Also don't use `$` inside `aes()`. You told ggplot that your data frame is `bplot`, don't keep repeating it (it messes with the aggregation that happens internally). `aes(x = reorder(Tool, Rating), y = Rating, fill = Process))`

Comment: @Gregor I have also removed $ inside aes() and am trying to execute it but am getting the same error.

Comment: I am not getting the plot as required. I have updated the question. Please see that again.

Comment: (a) I'd recommend removing *all* dollar signs from `aes()`. (b) Now that you know how to dodge, this has been reduced to a previously solved problem. Basically, if you want `ggplot` to plot 0-height bars, you'll need 0's in your data. I'd recommend `tidyr::complete` for this. Here are some duplicates: [Don't drop zero-count dodged barplot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10326729/903061), and my own from 2012 [A way to always dodge a histogram](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10149571/903061).

Comment: @Gregor thanks a lot