# Standardizing width of barplot and error bar in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am just curious if you can standardize the width of the bars in a bar plot and consequently the error bars when making plots using ggplot.  I have data absent across some of my X factor variable (Hour.Bin), so that when I make the plot the width of each bar and error bar is adjusted to reflect data missing at that hour.

Here is the first and last couple rows of the dataframe I'm working with.  I've created summary statistics based on the HOBOLocation variable (5 levels) in order to make a barplot of means and standard deviation.

```
    Hour.Bin Lake.Livewell N     Mean    Median   SD        SE     HOBOLocation
1     5:00      Livewell   2 31.62550 31.6255 0.5055813 0.35750000 Flow Through
2     6:00      Livewell  59 30.91512 31.2680 1.0607782 0.13810156 Flow Through
3     7:00      Livewell 213 29.35422 29.6520 2.1084091 0.14446581 Flow Through
4     8:00      Livewell 325 29.24637 29.4520 1.6922953 0.09387165 Flow Through
5     9:00      Livewell 360 29.35180 29.3520 1.5650980 0.08248791 Flow Through
6    10:00      Livewell 366 29.57598 29.5520 1.5749769 0.08232536 Flow Through

    Hour.Bin Lake.Livewell   N   Mean    Median   SD        SE     HOBOLocation
51    14:00 Lake - Pelagic 125 30.77400 30.862 1.272879 0.1138497 Lake - Pelagic
52    15:00 Lake - Release  92 31.57482 31.268 2.016206 0.2102040 Lake - Release
53    15:00 Lake - Pelagic  81 30.98407 30.963 1.567551 0.1741724 Lake - Pelagic
54    16:00 Lake - Release  15 32.45160 31.472 2.676622 0.6911008 Lake - Release
55    16:00 Lake - Pelagic  14 32.37864 32.813 1.662311 0.4442713 Lake - Pelagic
56     <NA> Lake - Release   1      NaN     NA      NaN       NaN Lake - Release

p <- ggplot(data = subset(HOBOSummaryEverything,!is.na(levels(Hour.Bin)[Hour.Bin])), aes(x = Hour.Bin, y = Mean, fill=HOBOLocation))+theme_bw()
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour="gray50",position = position_dodge(0.75),width=0.55,alpha=0.7) +
geom_errorbar(limits, position = position_dodge(0.75), width = 0.30, colour="black", linetype = 1, size=1) +
ggtitle(expression(atop(bold("Mean Temps by HOBO Location"), atop(italic("All Tournaments"), "")))) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray30","gray60","gray90","green","blue"), labels=c("Flow Through", "Water Recirculation", "Flow Through and Water  Recirculation", "Release","Pelagic"))+
scale_y_continuous(expression(bold("Temp"*~(degree*C))),limits=c(0.0,40.0),breaks=seq(0.0,40.0,by=5.0),labels=fmt(),expand=c(0.02,0.02))+
scale_x_discrete("Hour Bin",limits=c(levels(HOBOSummaryEverything$Hour.Bin)[1:12]))
```

The following plot is produced:

[image]

It's not a huge deal if I can't make the bar widths and error bar widths the same, but I figured I'd see if there was an easy solution.  Just to be clear on what I want to produce, I would like the bar width to be same as when all 5 factor levels have data present within an Hour Bin (which is true for most of my hours), even for hours like 5:00 which only has data one factor level (Flow Through).

Comment: There is now `preserve` argument in `position_dodge` in the development version of *ggplot2* (version 2.2.1.9000).  You could change that to `"single"` or use `position_dodge2`, which defaults to `"single"`.

Comment: So I just came across that.  I think that might be my solution.  I have to get administrative rights through IT where I work to update R.  I have one question, based on the examples I've seen.  If I am able to get the single `"single"` argument to work once I update R, is there a way to center the bar on the x variable (in my case Hour Bin), even though not all factor levels for HOBOLocation are present at that x location.  In the mtcars example I've seen online, it does not center the bar, it looks like it positions it to the left.

Comment: Looks like `position_dodge2` actually [centers each group of bars](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2076#issuecomment-319488025).

Comment: There are more manual ways if you can't get the dev version installed. This is a pretty common question, see, e.g., [Always dodge a histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10149571/903061), [Don't drop 0-count dodged bars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10326729/903061), etc.

Comment: @Gregor thanks for the links to those questions.  I think @aosmith is right though, `position_dodge2` is likely my solution as it centers the remaining non-zero bars at each discrete x.  I'm not really concerned with showing the zeros.